# Print all possible combination of words of length 10 from a list letters with repeating 'A' exactly twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-itertools

I have a list of 5 letters ['A', 'B', 'N', 'M','E'].

I want to print all the words **(word means a sequence of letters, it doesn't have to be a valid English word)** of length 10 letters that have exactly two letters A.
Order is important.

I have tried with itertools.product as it appeared to be the most promising solution:

```
from itertools import product

letters = ['A', 'B', 'N', 'M','E']

for word in product(letters, repeat=10):
    res = ''.join(str(x) for x in word)
    print(res)
```

The problem with this approach is that I can't really control the number of occurrences of the letter A as it returns the word composed of 10 letters of A.

Is there a solution for this?
Thanks

**EDIT 1**
Example of possible words:
BANAMEMNEB : it has only twice the letter A, we don't care about other letters.

Comment: examples of valid words to be clear...?

Comment: @D.L done! i added an example of acceptable word

Comment: thanks for the example, but `BANAMEMNEB` is not a word (from the english dictionary),  how is this generated ?

Comment: by a word, I mean a sequence of letters, it doesn't have to be meaningful. all that I care about is the repetition of the letter A that have to be exactly twice.

Comment: so basically every permutation with A occuring twice....  use `itertools`, the result will be large.

Comment: There are 2949120 possible outcomes. What do you plan to do with them? How is printing them useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it **efficiently** is to iterate over all combinations of the positions of the letters 'A', and for each such combination - iterate over all the ways *other letters* can be positioned, and just insert the 'A's there.

**Be warned that with your inputs this will produce almost 3 million words!**

On my machine it was printing the words for so long that I had to manually stop execution.

So here is the smaller example:

```py
letters = ['A', 'b', 'c']
num_As = 2
num_total = 4

from itertools import combinations, product
for indices_A in combinations(range(num_total), num_As):
    for rest in product(letters[1:], repeat=num_total - num_As):
        rest = list(rest)
        for index_A in indices_A:
            rest.insert(index_A, 'A')
        print(''.join(rest))
```

```py
AAbb
AAbc
AAcb
AAcc
AbAb
AbAc
AcAb
AcAc
AbbA
AbcA
AcbA
AccA
bAAb
bAAc
cAAb
cAAc
bAbA
bAcA
cAbA
cAcA
bbAA
bcAA
cbAA
ccAA
```

Comment: Be aware that you're looking for a large number, here. There are 5\*\*10 – almost 10 million – 10-letter words that you can make from an alphabet of 5 letters. Of those 10 million, almost 3 million ([10 choose 2]x4\*\*8 = 2,949,120) have exactly two A's. So even generating just the valid ones is going to take a while.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically @Vladimir-Fokow's answer translated to your use case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import combinations, product
letters =  ['A', 'B', 'N', 'M','E']
first, rest = letters[0], letters[1:]
total_length = 10
first_count = 2
for others in product(rest, repeat=total_length - first_count):
  for indices in combinations(range(total_length),first_count):
    result = list(others)
    for i in indices:
      result.insert(i,first)
    print(''.join(result))
```

On my iMac this only took about 3 seconds to print out all 2,949,120 words.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to filter out the words that do not contain exactly two 'A', as in the following simple code:

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter

letters = ['A', 'B', 'N', 'M','E']

for word in product(letters, repeat=10):
    res = ''.join(word)  # equivalent to res = ''.join(str(x) for x in word) !
    ctr = Counter(res)
    if ctr['A'] == 2:
        print(res)
```

This can also be written with one-line style coding, as follows:

```
res = [''.join(w) for w in product(letters, repeat=10) if Counter(w)['A'] == 2]
```

Comment: Thank you Laurent for your answer. Unfortunately, this is not the optimal solution since I have to generate all the possible sequences (with any number of the letter A) and then test if it has two letters of A. If possible, I want to generate only words with twice A from the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

First determine the two indices where the letter "A" will occur, then produce the letters at the other 8 indices:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

def solve():
    for i, j in combinations(range(10), 2):
        for b in map(list, product("BNME", repeat=8)):
            b.insert(i, "A")
            b.insert(j, "A")
            yield "".join(b)
```

To print:

```
for s in solve():
    print(s)
```

...but don't wait for it. There are 9*10/2 * 4<sup>8</sup> possible combinations, which is almost 3 million.